# vim automated replacement

Tags: vim, replace

I have an automatic replacement done by my vim setup, which systematically replaces all occurences of "sql" in command line by "SQL".

So when I type:
    :e myfile.sql
it is translated in
    :e myfile.SQL

and when I search
    /sql
it is tranlasted in
    /SQL

There's probably some parameters in the .vimrc, or some file sourced by .vimrc that generates this behaviour (I do not have control of everything that the .vimrc does since there's some amount of corporate .vimrc involved here), but I find myself unable to localize the part of setup that does this, or to desactivate it retroactively.

Can somebody who knows vim well help?
I have vim 7.1, running on Linux

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably an abbreviation set as follows:

`abbrev sql SQL`

The Vim documentation tells you how to determine the last location where an abbreviation was defined:

> *:abbreviate-verbose*
>
> When 'verbose' is non-zero, listing an abbreviation will also display where it
>   was last defined.  Example:
>
> ```
> :verbose abbreviate
> !  teh       the
>     Last set from /home/abcd/vim/abbr.vim
> ```

So typing `:verbose abbreviate` should help you locate the SQL abbreviation.

Comment: Perfectly relevant answer, helped me solve the issue in 2 minutes. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmap sql SQL
```

maybe?